# How do you iterate with an offset in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iteration, each

Given HTML...

```
<ol>
    <li>The seventh</li>
    <li>8th</li>
    <li>(10-1)</li>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>Trois</li>
</ol>
<ol>
    <li>Fourth</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>Number six</li>
</ol>​
```

And JavaScript code...

```
$("li").each(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});​
```

How can I [**offset**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_%28computer_science%29) the iteration order so that it starts on element `<li>One</li>` and ends on element `<li>(10-1)</li>`?

[Code sample available on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QwwQ7/).

Comment: It is hard to understand the context and essence of the question. jQuery provides `each` as a convenience, but writing a loop is usually easy unless there is something tricky about your specific situation. Also, is sorting spelled out numbers an essential part of your problem?

Comment: We're not sorting at all! I'm looking for an *offset*.

Comment: You keep using that word. [I do not think it means what you think it means](http://api.jquery.com/offset). I suppose that you want it to arbitrarily start on the nth `li` and then loop back to the top?

Comment: @Blazemonger That's the way I read it. When you fetch the jQuery collection, it comes back in DOM order. He'd like to iterate over the collection starting at an arbitrary index but still covering the whole set.

Comment: @Mathletics - Yes! I declare you my new best friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a normal JavaScript loop:

```
var $query = $("li");

var count = $query.length;
var offset = 2;
for(var i=0; i<count; i++) {
    var domEl = $query.get((i + offset)%count);
    //alert(domEl.getAttribute("class"));
    alert($(domEl).attr("class"));
}
```

[Code on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whcLA/).

Comment: This is a better version of my answer.

Comment: @Mathletics - I kind of wish you didn't delete answer; now I have to remember to come back to this question in two days to accept my answer.

Comment: undeleted, though I maintain your answer is better.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe nothing better for your case:

```
$.each(["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", ...], function(i, v) {
    var $this = $("li." + v);
    // ...
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZapyJ/2/

Comment: "six", "seven", "eight".... Your solution is too specific and can't be extended to larger numbers.

Answer (score 4):

You can't reasonably expect JavaScript to intelligently sort English-language numbers in numerical order without a lot of extra work. Far better to add a `data-` attribute with a numerical order, and then extract those with a simple `for` loop.

HTML:

```
<ol>
    <li data-num="4">Four</li>
    <li data-num="5">Five</li>
    <li data-num="1">One</li>
    <li data-num="2">Two</li>
    <li data-num="3">Three</li>
</ol>
​
```

JS:

```
var max = $('li').length;
for (var i=1; i<max; i++) {
    var txt = $('li[data-num='+i+']').text();
    alert(txt);
};​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/ZapyJ/1/

Comment: You're right - it wont sort english-language numbers, but you can *teach it to do so* ;)

Comment: Doing so for a known, limited quantity of words is trivial. But is the OP going to stop at eight, or might this conceivably go up to twenty-two? Parsing English-language numbers into integers is a complicated and distinct problem. The best solution is to bypass it.

Comment: pfft, it could go up to a million and the same solution would still work, you just have to construct the array.

Comment: @Jamiec That's only a solution in the most literal sense of the word. We must not encourage such insanity.

Comment: What is insane about providing an array which represents a sort order for strings? They could be english-language numbers, they could be animal species or any language-based string you wish to fix a sort order for. I have used this technique countless times, and I see nothing insane about it whatsoever. Granted the "million" comment was a bit trite, but the concept is sound IMO.

Comment: +1 - Although I can't modify the HTML structure, and my original HTML doesn't use numeric string names at all (I chose those arbitrarily for readability and it seems to have completly sidetracked the answers). What I wanted was an offset, not a sort order - and this answer provides that.

Comment: @Jamiec The insanity is that such a code block is unmaintainable -- every time the HTML is extended, the JavaScript needs to be edited. *HTML and JavaScript should be separated from each other as much as possible.* If your code is useful ONLY to a specific block of HTML, you've sacrificed modularity. Better in that case to just rewrite the HTML by hand.

Answer (score 3):

```
var arr = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
$("li").sort(function(a, b) {
    return arr.indexOf(a.className) > arr.indexOf(b.className)
}).each(function() {
    console.log(this.className)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r55BY/

Comment: Oh snap, beaten again by a few seconds. +1 I s'pose!

Comment: @Jamiec It's slightly hackish, but there is no other bulletproof logic in this case. +1

Answer (score 3):

The addition of a `sortOrder` array, and a call to `.sort()`:

```
var sortOrder = ['one','two','three','four','five'];

$("li").sort(function(a,b){ 
          return sortOrder.indexOf($(a).attr('class')) 
             - sortOrder.indexOf($(b).attr('class')); })
       .each(function() {
          alert($(this).attr("class"));
       });
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/XatzB/

Comment: I actually prefer this solution; I chose the class names arbitrarily for readability without realizing they would present a new solution!

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen - it matters not what you want to use to order your elements, what matters for this is that you have some idetifier which can be used to `indexOf` into an array used to define the sortOrder

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
var $list = $("li");
​    
for (var i=2, l = $list.length, len = l + 2; i < len; i++) {
    alert($list.eq(i % l).attr('class'));
}​
```

There isn't really a nice way to reorder a collection in jQuery, but you can use the collection length and offset to generate an arbitrary loop. I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to figure out the starting index dynamically, which I assume you'd need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Don't paint yourself into a corner using classes like "one", "two", and "three". Rather, auto-generate a sortable attribute value like `data-order`, which will have digits as values:

```
<li data-order=7>Seven</li>
<li data-order=8>Eight</li>
<li data-order=1>One</li>
```

By using the `data-order` attribute (name it whatever you like), we can easily sort these items in a collection and then iteratively modify them in their natural order:

```
$('li[data-order]').sort(sortByData).text(changeText);

function sortByData (one, two) {
    return $(one).data("order") - $(two).data("order");
}

function changeText (index, value) {
   return index + " " + value; 
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2MYJ3/1/
    ​

Comment: Your demo doesn't seem to be doing what you want.

Comment: @Blazemonger Actually, it does... What is it doing for you?

Comment: @Blazemonger Yes, collections are zero-based in JavaScript, so the 7th item is at index 6, and the eigth is at index 7, and the first is at index 0. This is why `['foo'][0]` returns `'foo'`, and `['foo'][1]` does not.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own method, here's how I'd do it (and it took me quite some time to figure out)

```
$.fn.offsetEach = function(offset, cb) {
  $(this.get().splice(offset).concat(this.get().splice(0,offset))).each(cb);
}
```

and it works exactly like jQuery's `each()` method, except for the added offset parameter

```
$("li").offsetEach(integer_offset, function(index, element) {
     // iterates through all elements, but starts with an offset index
});
```

The offset is zero based, so for your example you would do it like this to start with `One`

```
$("li").offsetEach(3, function() {
     alert( $(this).text() );
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/QwwQ7/2/)